# Redirecting only selected lines to a script

Tags: sed, scripting, io-redirection

Suppose I have a python script, which normally would be executed as

```
python s.py
```

Instead of having to type data in manually, I'd like to forward a file, `text.txt`, as an input:

```
 python s.py < text.txt
```

Now, this `text.txt` contains more lines than `s.py` asks for, because it is supposed to cover several passes: first I'm feeding lines 1-7 of `text.txt`, then lines 8-14, then 15-21 etc. I'm going to take care of it by using a loop, but I can't figure out how to input only lines 1-7 of `text.txt` into `python s.py`. I tried something like

```
python s.py < sed -n 1,7p txt.txt
```

and

```
python s.py < cat txt.txt | sed -n 1,7p
```

, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: why not get the needed slices inside the python script itself?

Comment: If I have several thousands of lines and, thus, need several hundreds of `python s.py` executions, I wouldn't want to overcomplicate the `s.py` by making it aware of which pass we are currently at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pipe:

```
sed -n 1,7p txt.txt | python s.py
```